# Javascript not working in simple HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple app that rolls dice fairly once, then unfairly afterwards (a friend is in a behavioral studies class). I've never written javascript or html before, so I'm assuming there's a rookie mistake here, but I can't find it. It seems to me like the javascript part of this page is not even running, but I can't figure out why.

I'm writing it in Atom, saving as a .html and then opening in google chrome to test, if that matters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dice</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function rollDiceF() {
  var sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length);
  var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length);
  var n1 = sides[v1].toString();
  var n2 = sides[v2].toString();
  document.getElementById("myval").innerHTML = n1;
  //document.getElementById("n2").innerHTML = n2;
  //return choices[[sides[v1], sides[v2]];
}

function rollDiceNF() {
  var sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  if n%2 == 0 {
    var s2 = [1, 3, 5];
  }
  else {
    var s2 = [2, 4, 6];
  }
  var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length);
  var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * s2.length);
  var nf1 = sides[v1].toString();
  var nf2 = s2[v2].toString();
  document.getElementById("myval").innerHTML = nf1;
  document.getElementById("n2").innerHTML = nf2;
  //return([sides[v1], s2[v2]]);

}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="rollDiceF()">

<h1 align='center'>Dice</h1>
<p align='center'>The world's number one dice app</p>

<p align='center'>You rolled a: <span id="myval"></span></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't display a number. The text displays correctly. I basically copied and pasted this from someone else's code

Comment: You just have a couple of basic syntax errors (edit: actually, I think it may just be one -- nice work for a newbie!). You can see where they are by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Shift+I on MacOS) depending on what browser you use to open the dev tools, then click the Console tab. It will show you the errors (the condition in an `if` statement must be in `()`, for instance), with a link to the line that has the problem. (I'm a bit surprised they're not being highlighted by Atom. You might look at using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code.) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea there was a way to see the output.

Comment: Yup! And in the Source/Sources/Debug tab, you can see the code, insert breakpoints, etc. If you search for "XYZ devtools" where XYZ = your browser, you'll find info on how to use them. Makes all the difference. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You missed parentheses at `if` in `function rollDiceNF()`

```
function rollDiceNF() {
  var sides = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  if (n%2 == 0) {
    var s2 = [1, 3, 5];
  }
  else {
    var s2 = [2, 4, 6];
  }
  var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length);
  var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * s2.length);
  var nf1 = sides[v1].toString();
  var nf2 = s2[v2].toString();
  document.getElementById("myval").innerHTML = nf1;
  document.getElementById("n2").innerHTML = nf2;
  //return([sides[v1], s2[v2]]);

}
```

Comment: Simple errors like this don't need answers, just comments (I've already done that) and close votes (when you have enough rep).